# Emphasize line in minted code

Tags: minted

Is there a way to stress/emphasize a line (or part of it for that matter) in `minted` code?

The `listings` package has the `moredelim`-option for that purpose.

Comment: This is possible by the correct setting of `pygmentize`. The package `minted` doesn't format the code that the task of `pygmentize`.

Comment: Ok thanks, i've found the option `hl_lines` for pygmentize. Is there a way to pass this to `pygmentize` when starting a code block?

Comment: Not really. You can create your own new key.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little, i don't know what you're suggesting. What do you mean by "key"?

Comment: Pygmentize doesn’t support the `hl_lines` option for the LaTeX formatter, and by extension, neither does minted, sorry. It wouldn’t help either to include this key in minted – Pygments would just ignore it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: That explains why my test fails ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Konrad Rudolph pointed out you can't expand pygmentize with the option `\hl_lines`.

> Pygmentize doesn’t support the `hl_lines` option for the LaTeX formatter, and by extension, neither does minted, sorry.

I have another suggestion. You can use tikz to emphasize special lines.

Here the code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\def\theFancyVerbLine{%
  \rmfamily\tiny\arabic{FancyVerbLine}%
  {\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node(minted-\arabic{FancyVerbLine}){};}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}[linenos]{bash}
#!/bin/bash
SOURCE="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
while [ -h "$SOURCE" ] ; do SOURCE="$(readlink "$SOURCE")"; done
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )" && pwd )"
java -jar "$DIR/arara.jar" $*
\end{minted}

\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\draw[fill=yellow,opacity=0.2] ([yshift=-0.05cm,xshift=0.3cm]minted-2) rectangle ([yshift=0.35cm,xshift=5.5cm]minted-2);

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, i like this idea! A little syntactic sugar in form of a generic command might be convenient. I defined a new command, which takes a single argument and interprets that as the lineno. Just need a way to figure out the width...

Comment: @sschober: This is related to fancyvrb. The environment of the code is provided by this package.

Comment: @Marco: Thx, I'll look into `fancyvrb` then...

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by the correct setting of pygmentize. The package minted doesn't format the code that the task of pygmentize.

Comment: can you please be more specific?